# Unable to get animations to work correctly in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fadeout

I just recently started learning [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery). To help me learn, I started redesigning [this](http://www.mjbox.info) website. The problems I have at the moment are:

1. Once a thumb image is clicked and the main post loads; after closing the main post and when hovering over the thumbs again, the title and post information no longer fade in above and beside the thumbs.
2. When hovering over a thumb image for the first time, you should notice that it hides everything (including itself) and then shows itself again, this gives the illusion that it flickers. How can I stop this?

Here is the .js file containing the jQuery code:

```
$(".post").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).children(".post_title, .post_info").stop(true).fadeIn();
        $(this).children(".link-to-post").stop().show();
        $(".post").stop().fadeTo(0,0.2);
        $(this).fadeTo(300,1);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).parent().find(".post_title, .post_info").stop(true).hide();
        $(this).parent().find(".link-to-post").stop().hide();
        $(".post").stop().fadeTo(300,1);
    });

    $(".cover-img").click(function(){
        $("#main-post").fadeIn(1000);
        $.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: $(this).data('postid')},
            function(output){
                $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
            }).fail(function(x,y,z){
                $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
            });
        $('.post').fadeTo(0,0);
    });

    $('input[name=close]').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('#main-post').hide();
```

Each thumbnail is within its own class:

```
// Retrieve all active posts order by lastest first
$resultarray = retrieve_active_posts();

echo '<div id="content-wrap">';
foreach($resultarray AS $value){
    $filename = substr($value['img_file_name'],9);
    $cat_id = $value['cat_id'];
    echo '<article class="post">';
    echo '<div class="post_title">' . stripslashes(stripslashes($value['post_title'])) . '</div>';
    echo '<div class="post_info">' .
    'Category: ' . $cat_name = get_cat_name($cat_id) .'<br />'.
    'Year: ' . $value['post_year'] .'<br />'.
    stripslashes($value['post_desc']) .'<br />'.
    '</div>';
    echo '<div class="link-to-post"><a href="#">Click to view</a></div>';
    echo '<a href="#'.$value['post_id'].'" class="linktopost"><img class="post-thumb" src="img/thumb_/'.$filename.'" alt="MJbox Michael Jackson memorabilia thumbnail" data-postid="'.$value['post_id'].'"/></a>';
    echo '<a href="#'.$value['post_id'].'" class="linktopost"><img class="cover-img" src="img/post-bg-1.png" alt="test" data-postid="'.$value['post_id'].'"/></a>';
    echo '</article>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll have another go :-)

I've looked on the Google Developer Tools and it looks like this is the problem...

```
 $('.post').fadeTo(0,0);
```

It is leaving the opacity attribute as 0. When I override this in developer tools, the popups show again. Try changing it to:

```
 $('.post').fadeOut;
```

or even

```
 $('.post').hide();
```

Should do the trick.

I'm pretty sure I have the answer to the other problem:

You have two animations. You are fading all of the .post items out and then fading $(this) back in again. You need this solution:

```
$(".post").hover(
function () {
    $(this).children(".post_title, .post_info").stop(true).fadeIn();
    $(this).children(".link-to-post").stop().show();
    $(this).siblings.().stop().fadeTo(0,0.2);
},
```

This will fade out only the other ones so you don't have to fade $(this) back in again!

Fingers crossed!

---

I have tested this. It fixes both problems and also stops the browser going to the top of the page when you click one of the thumbs.

Here is the complete jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fancybox").fancybox();


$("#login").click(function(){
    $("#searchform").hide();
    $("#loginform").fadeIn('3000','swing'); 
});

$("#search").click(function(){
    $("#loginform").hide();
    $("#searchform").fadeIn('3000','swing');    

});

$(".post").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children(".post_title, .post_info").stop(true).fadeIn();
    $(this).children(".link-to-post").stop().show();
    $(this).siblings().stop().fadeTo(0,0.2);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".post_title, .post_info").stop(true).hide();
    $(this).parent().find(".link-to-post").stop().hide();
    $(".post").stop().fadeTo(300,1);
  });

  $(".cover-img").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#main-post").fadeIn(1000);
    $.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: $(this).data('postid')},
        function(output){
            $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
        }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
            $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
        });
    $('.post').fadeOut();

 });

 $('input[name=close]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('#main-post').hide();

 });
```

});

Just cut and paste this in place of your code.

Chris

Comment: Nope no fixers there. If you take a look at the site perhaps it will help to see what is happening. When I click a thumbnail, the post loads centre screen, then when I close the post and hover over a thumbnail again the .post_title and .post_info divs do not show anymore.

Comment: Try my edit. You need the preventDefault to stop the page going to the top when someone clicks on the thumb. With the fadeTo changed to a fadeOut the .post_title and .post_info divs still display once you have clicked a thumb. Also the flicker has gone with the .siblings() change so there is only one animation.

Comment: The flicker has stopped but when the post is closed and I hover over another thumbnail the .post_title and .post_info divs dont fade in. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

This is for your first problem.

Try doing ...

```
$(".cover-img").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        .... rest of your code
```

This prevents the default behaviour of the browser to follow the link. This may solve your first problem but should be in there anyway with click events.

Comment: Welcome to stack, thanks for the attempt but it didn't fix the first problem.